# Races not showing in correct order

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to be able to get the database results that are closest to the current time.

Currently my shows like this

[image]

How ever as you can see it shows all races from one meeting isntead of getting ones that are closest to the time.

Should look like some thing like

> Question how can I make sure it displays the up and coming races correctly instead of being from one lot of races meetings.

[image]

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('meeting');
        $this->meeting->new_meetings();
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $data['races'] = $this->upandcomingraces();

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    public function upandcomingraces() {
        $timestamp_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $this->db->select('meeting.*, races.*');
        $this->db->from('meeting');
        $this->db->join('races', 'races.meeting_number = meeting.meeting_number', 'left');
        $this->db->where('races.racing_datetime >=', $timestamp_now);
        $this->db->limit(10);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

Database

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ordering it by `racing_datetime`  :

```
... 
$this->db->where('races.racing_datetime >=', $timestamp_now);
$this->db->order_by('races.racing_datetime', 'asc');
...
```